# poisson distribution,and coding.

Tags: poisson-distribution

prove that if random variable, Y= k X, where k is a non-zero constant and X follows Poisson distribution with mean λ, then Y also follows Poisson distribution with mean kλ.

Is it true, if then, How can I prove it?

Comment: Poisson distribution is concentrated on $\Bbb N$ (zero included), but $kX$ is concentrated on $k\Bbb N=\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, \frac xk\in\Bbb N\}$, which is a different set. It's obviously true that $E[kX]=k\lambda$, but it isn't a Poisson distribution.

Comment: thank you! then there is any other name for this distribution for Y?

Comment: I am not aware of any, but that doesn't mean much.